# android SDK errors (BNR)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hey guys i'm trying to learn the Android SDK and I bought the Big Nerd on Ranch book on it by Bill Phillips & Brian Hardy but I am stuck on chapter 9 with errors everywhere that I can't resolve.  I got 5 errors here and they all say 'cannot resolve (symbol)'.  All of these symbols exist in my program so I don't understand why it can't find them.  Here is my main class CrimeListFragment.java.  The code is a bit long but I labeled where all the errors appear with comments(may need to scroll right).

CrimeListFragment.java

```
package criminalintent.android.bignerdranch.com.criminalintent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.R;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Matt on 7/28/2014.
 */
public class CrimeListFragment extends ListFragment {
    private ArrayList<Crime> mCrimes;
    private static final String TAG = "CrimeListFragment";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.crime_title); //ERROR here 'crime_title'
        mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes();
        CrimeAdapter adapter = new CrimeAdapter(mCrimes);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Crime c = ((CrimeAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);
        Log.d(TAG, c.getTitle() + " was clicked");
    }

    private class CrimeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Crime> {

        public CrimeAdapter(ArrayList<Crime> crimes) {
            super(getActivity(), 0, crimes);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup part) {
            //If we werent given a view, inflate one
            if(convertView == null) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                        .inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime,null);//ERROR 'list_item_crime'
            }

            //Configure the view for this Crime
            Crime c = getItem(position);

            TextView titleTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_titleTextView);//ERROR 'crime_list_item_titleTextView'
            titleTextView.setText(c.getTitle());
            TextView dateTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_dateTextView);//ERROR 'crime_list_item_dateTextView'
            dateTextView.setText(c.getDate().toString());
            CheckBox solvedCheckBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_solvedCheckBox);//ERROR 'crime_list_item_solvedCheckBox'
            solvedCheckBox.setChecked(c.isSolved());

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">CriminalIntent</string>
    <string name="title_activity_crime">CrimeActivity</string>
    <string name="crime_title_hint">Enter a title for this crime</string>
    <string name="crime_title_label">Title</string>
    <string name="crime_details_label">Details</string>
    <string name="crime_solved_label">Solved?</string>
    <string name="crime_title">Crimes</string>

</resources>
```

And list_item_crime.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/crime_list_item_solvedCheckBox"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/crime_list_item_titleTextView"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/crime_list_item_solvedCheckBox"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:text="Crime title"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/crime_list_item_dateTextView"
        android:layout_below="@id/crime_list_item_titleTextView"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/crime_list_item_solvedCheckBox"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:text="Crime date"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you need any more resources please let me know.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

you have the wrong `R` import (`import android.R;`). Delete that line and import the one that belongs to your project

Comment: What do you mean by 'the one that belongs to your project'?  My project was having trouble finding R and I looked online and an article told me to 'import android.R' so i did it and it fixed my R problems then these problems arised.

Comment: R is generated at compile times. If you are not able to import youtpackage.R probably it means that you have errors in the res/ folder

Comment: You mean the folder with Android manifest, drawable, layout, strings.xml, etc...?  I don't have errors in there.

Comment: How do I figure out my package name?

Answer (score 0):

You were right blackbelt, I did have an error in my fragment_crime.xml.  I had a layout_width and a width.  After I removed one it fixed the R error, I didn't need to import anything.  Thanks for the help.